# How to remote upload large files without setting time/memory limit and show progress info in PHP?

Tags: php

How could I use PHP to remote upload remote/third-party **large** files (1GB+) to my server (where server provider **disabled** modifying **memory limit**  and **time limit** setting) with showing uploading process **status** (refreshing every 1s) to tell **progress** (how much of the file has been uploaded till now), **transfer rate** (current uploading speed), and **time left** (estimated time to complete the uploading process)?

I'm trying to remote upload remote/third-party files to my server. For example, let's say I've a link for a large file that I want to have a copy of on my server `http://website.com/path/to/file.ext`. What I'm looking for is a process to remote upload this file to my server with showing progress, knowing that I'm not allowed to modify either the memory limit nor the time limit settings.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC I'm not trying to echo files to users, I'm trying to get (download remotely, remote upload) files to my server.

Comment: The concept your are striving for is known as streaming, and this idea is shown in the linked post!

Comment: @FatBoyXPC "I have a 200MB file that I want to give to a user via download". I'm not trying to give the user any files via download. I downloading files to server itself from a third-party location. However concept may be the same, this shouldn't be a reason to mark question as as duplicate.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC Also, I'm asking about how to show the progress while downloading large file to server.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the progress bar bit, and I'm not even sure it's possible. I haven't done a lot of file reading with PHP, but I imagine the only way to do a progress bar is if during the initial read of the file it tells you the entire file size, so you can then compare that to the amount you've downloaded.

Streaming is the only way to do this that I'm aware of that won't just eat up all the memory, so just look into it and see what you can do? The thread I provided at least shows how to accomplish that.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC I've added that I'm not able to modify time limit.

Comment: You had that posted originally, too. You shouldn't need to modify the memory limit if you stream the file.

Comment: Have you tried modifying these values in htaccess? If you can't change the time or memory limits, I am not of any other option.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC Yes It's not possible to modify time or memory limits as I'm on a sharing hosting that disables modifying any of them even by the htaccess method. I think there should be a way doing this in chunks regarding processing time issue like we did in chunks for memory issue.

Comment: The problem is that you can't really change how fast something happens. How much do you pay for your hosting? You can get really cheap and decent hosting for $5/month.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC I'm on $1/month plan. Unfortunately I can't afford the $5/month plan for now.

Comment: You're just out of luck, then. If you can't modify time or memory limits, and what you are trying to do exceeds those...pretty simple equation.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC I believe there might be a solution or workaround with this specific situation (no modification for memory and time limit).

Comment: @FatBoyXPC Could you please remove the duplicate flag as it's now a distinct question.